# Can AKS be configured to work with an Azure private DNS zone?

Tags: aws-fargate, azure-aks

I'm porting an application to Azure that was orignally developed for Amazon's Fargate facility. A feature of Fargate is being able to create a private DNS zone and have the service names that it creates automatically register with this zone. This allows any Fargate service, as well as other VMs in the same VPC/subnet, to be able to reference the services by name using `service-name.zone-name`.

This is particularly useful for the VMs we have running in our product since they can make REST calls to the microservices running in Fargate directly by their automatically generated private DNS names.

We're using AKS in our Azure implementation and I've discovered that kubernetes provides a similar mechanism for the containers that it manages by creating records of the form `service-name.namespace` that map to the cluster IP of the services. This works fine within the kubernetes network but any VMs we have running in the same virtual network are unaware of these AKS service aliases.

So my question is this: Is there a way to make use of Azure's private DNS facility and tie it into AKS so that VMs that live in the same virtual network can also refer to the Kubernetes services by name rather than by IP address?

Answer (score 5):

you could use the [external-dns](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns/blob/master/docs/faq.md#running-an-internal-and-external-dns-service) for this. The trick is to use the helm chart available [here](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/external-dns) and add the `publishInternalServices=true` to your values.yaml. This way ClusterIP's services will be added to your internal Azure DNS zone.

Comment: I'll give this a try. Thanks for the lead.

Comment: would be awesome if you could upvote my answer, if it leads to some improvement. I'm building stack overflow rep :) thanks

Comment: If this leads me to a solution I'll definitely give you an upvote. I've only had a chance to give this a quick read and my biggeste concern is that this talks about using an external DNS. I don't want to expose publically accessible names for my services but rather use a private DNS zone and generate names that are viisible only within my vnet where my VMs and cluster reside.

Comment: use ingresses and the external-dns watcher, which should work just fine with a private dns zone ("advanced" networking type of AKS cluster in a precreated VNET)

Comment: For those looking for this functionality with private DNS zones, there is an [open issue on external-dns](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns/issues/1073). It's not currently supported, only Azure public zones.